# Jquery explode works, but in some unusal way. Any thoughts?

Tags: jquery, explode

http://patrikmakrai.com/buttonka/ - This is the place where I try to make jquery's explode work, but it works in a weird way. Any thought why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="container">
<div id="buttonka">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#buttonka').click(function() {
        $('#buttonka').hide('explode');
});
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're downloading jQuery ui before jQuery itself. Change

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```